# Parent - Child components and data responsibilities (should child call API?)

Tags: reactjs

Thanks for any help!

If I have a Container component which has two children: Toolbar and Data

```
Container 
  - Toolbar
  - Data
```

Right now I have Container making the calls to the API to get the data, which is passed down as props to the Toolbar and Data components.

Say, Toolbar has a 'Publish' button, which when pressed needs to 1) Call the API to update the data and 2) Reload the Data Component

My question is:  Should the Toolbar component make the call directly to the API and then let the Container know the data has changed.  OR Should the Toolbar let the Container know that the 'Publish' button was called and the Container would then call the API (re: Toolbar should not directly make changes to the data via calls to to the API, the Container should handle all calls).  I feel the letting the container handle all data changes is the more appropriate answer as it allows the container to control the state/handle errors and properly update the child components, but at the same time it seems odd to not allow a child component be able to handle it's own data behavior and that it would pass off control to the container... i'm torn ;)

Or are both of these options incorrect and a better way exists?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I feel the letting the container handle all data changes is the more
>   appropriate answer as it allows the container to control the
>   state/handle errors and properly update the child components

Yes, generally this is the right pattern to follow. Consider that your container essentially serves as a single source of truth for your components. The data should flow in one direction from Parent to Children components.

However, Children should still be able trigger some sort of action on the Parent.

[image]

That's the standard Parent-Child relationship. Parent passes data to children and children emit events to Parent. Which means, the child should have some sort of function that tells the parent to do something.

The structure of your code would look something like:

**Container.js**

```
class Container extends React.Component{
   state = {
      data: []
   }

   componentDidMount(){
      this.getData()
   }

   getData = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("api")
      const data = await res.json()

      this.setState({
         data: data
      })
   }

   handleClick = () => {
      this.getData()
   }

   render(){
      <div>
          <Toolbar data={this.state.data} handleClick={this.handleClick}/>
          <Data data={this.state.data}/>
      </div>
   }
}
```

Note that we defined an event-handler in the Parent component and passed it down as a prop to the Child. That was intentional because the function itself needs to be bound to your Parent's execution context (hence the `this` keyword).

Now the child component can just use that event-handler to communicate with the Parent.

**Toolbar.js**

```
const Toolbar = ({data, handleClick}) => {
   return(
      <div>
         ...Markup
         <button onClick={handleClick}>Publish</button>
      </div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct you should handle API call via container which is correct pattern. You can have a function in container which will handle api call. Now pass this function to toolbar component where it will be mapped to onClick event of button.

Button -> toolbar --> conatiner --> api call